# How to add new dictionaries to /usr/share/dict/

Tags: catalina, sip

I'm trying to add a new word file to `/usr/share/dict/` on macOS Catalina v 10.15.1 and I'm getting:

```
$ sudo touch /usr/share/dict/mywords
touch: /usr/share/dict/mywords: Operation not permitted
# touch /usr/share/dict/mywords
touch: /usr/share/dict/mywords: Operation not permitted
```

I've read some guides online for similar issues that recommend going into the security & privacy settings and granting your terminal application "Full Disk Access".  However I have already done that.  Other suggestions include completely disabling SIP which I would like to avoid.  Does anyone know of another way to give me full access to my filesystem? Or at least access to the directories I need as I need them?

Comment: You can disable SIP to make the change (if that works), and the re-enable it. You might also try logging into the root account and making changes from there.